# String list arithmetics with Python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How can I do that?

```
>>> a
['eins', 'zwei', 'drei', 'vier', 'fünf']
>>> b
['eins', 'zwei', 'drei']
>>> c = a - b
```

This doesn't work, too.

```
c = a[:].remove(b)
```

Comment: Just use sets. For example `set(a).difference(b)`

Comment: `[i for i in a if i not in b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need repeated elements you could use `set`s as jadelord said

If list `a` has repeated elements and you need them you should use

```
c = list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a))
```

Or

```
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a functionality associated with the `set` datatype in python. Not `lists`!

This should solve your problem:

```
c = list(set(a) - set(b))
```

Comment: This is only if OP doesn't want repeated elements

Comment: If there are repetitions in list `a` then, list comprehension mentioned in the comments above is the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of Set and ImmutableSet both provide the following operations:

```
Operation        Equivalent     Result
len(s)                          cardinality of set s
x in s                          test x for membership in s
x not in s                      test x for non-membership in s
s.issubset(t)      s <= t       test whether every element in s is in t
s.issuperset(t)    s >= t       test whether every element in t is in s
s.union(t)          s | t       new set with elements from both s and t
s.intersection(t)   s & t       new set with elements common to s and t
s.difference(t)     s - t       new set with elements in s but not in t
s.symmetric_difference(t) s ^ t new set with elements in either s or t but not both
s.copy()                        new set with a shallow copy of s
```